# How to change the font size of the shapes in Telerik RadDiagram

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-ajax, raddiagram

I am using [RadDiagram](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/diagram/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) in my ASP.NET application. Control doesn't offer the ability of changing font size of shapes. Is there any way to change sizes?

I create shapes dynamically. Example:

```
label[i] = new DiagramShape();
label[i].Y = shape[5].Y + SHAPE_HEIGHT + LABEL_TOP_MARGIN;
label[i].X = shape[i].X - LABEL_LEFT_INDENT;
label[i].Height = 20;
label[i].Width = 20;
label[i].ContentSettings.Text = dateLabels[i] ;
label[i].Background = "#FFFFFF";
label[i].ContentSettings.Color = "#000000";
RadDiagram1.ShapesCollection.Add(label[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a template: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/diagram/functionality/shape-templates

There are some details in getting templates to work (for starters, you will need to implement a JS function for that) and then you will need to create a text block where you can set the font:

```
    var textBlock2 = new diagram.TextBlock({
        text: options.id,
        color: "#ffffff",
        fontSize: 16,
        x: 28,
        y: 50
    });
```

You can use server code blocks to obtain data from serer objects in the markup, or you can create the entire script on the server and register it via the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someKey", yourScriptString, true);` method